# Python4Delphi, support different Unix installations

Tags: delphi, python4delphi

I want to deploy a Delphi application on Linux, which will load a Python script and execute it.

My first demo application worked on my test system, a Linux Red Hat installation.  But I failed on different client installations, having Ubuntu and also different Python versions.

Is there any way to configure Python4Delphi to automatically match the used Linux and Python version? If not: is there a way to provide these details to the Delphi components, where/how to figure out which parameters must be set on the Linux client installations?

There should be a solution, acc. to [Ubuntu working example](https://github.com/pyscripter/python4delphi/issues/196).

Comment: How does that link help? How/why do you fail? What part exactly?

Comment: Could you build an MRE. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically detect installed python version is not possible , see answer here : [python 4 Delphi support , Delphi Praxis EN](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/4700-getregisteredpythonversions-for-linux/)